# how to use properly locale for dates in symfony2 (2.4 and up)

Tags: symfony, twig

How to use date locale properly in symfony2 Twig so that:

```
for GB browser I display format 27/10/2013 
for US browser I display format 10/27/2013
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I had to enable Intl twig extension which is by default included in symfony2 framework (**not enabled by default**)

Enable it by adding this in your config.yml (example src/Project/TestBundle/Resources/config/):

```
services:
    twig.extension.intl:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Then you use like this:

```
{{ 'now' | localizeddate('short', 'none') }} 
// outputs dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy depending on where browser is coming from
```

If this does not work automaticaly then you need to force to use Prefered Language by the browser like this (in your controller)

```
$this->getRequest()->setLocale($this->getRequest()->getPreferredLanguage());
```

This will use valid date format depending on browser's visitor settings (like Accept-Language header with value en_GB or en_US)

You can force to use certain locale by adding third parameter in localizeddate (example "de-DE"). To get current locale use {{ app.request.locale }}

Make note that twig documentation is a little bit out of date so its better to use what I did above

Comment: Works well, but the "short" date format will display dates like dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy. Do you know if there is a way to display dates in the dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy (full year) format depending on the locale?

Comment: my guess would be to investigate php IntlDateFormatter class http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php

Comment: This is what I did indeed, but I could not find any way to just use yyyy instead of yy for any locale...
Thanks again for the help anyway!